# calculate fibonacci sequence position from user inserted value

Tags: ruby, foreach, fibonacci

Below is my full program's code:

```
GradeAvg = [[59, 'F'], [69, 'D'], [79, 'C'], [89, 'B'], [100, 'A']]

def letter_grade
  num = number_grade
  _, letter = GradeAvg.find { |n, _| num <= n }
  [num, letter]
end

def number_grade
  loop do
    puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
    num = gets.to_i
    break(num) if (1..100).cover?(num)
  end
end

def fib(n)
  return n if n < 2

  fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end

10.times { print letter_grade; (num).each { |n| puts fib(n) }; puts }
```

It is failing with the below error:

```
undefined local variable or method `num' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Why can't I apply my fibonacci sequence calculation on my acceptable user inserted value in variable `num`?

Comment: What is your actual goal here? What do you want the program to do?

Comment: calculate number which occupies the position selected by the user in fibonacci sequence -

Comment: The error message is not lying to you. At the top level of this script, you are trying to iterate over a variable called `num` which is not defined at the top-level. What vales are you expecting to iterate over?

Comment: num is populated via user inserted value

Comment: Doc, further to @naomik's comment, you need to state your question in words at the outset. The title seems to come close but "inserted value" is vague. In general, readers should not be expected to decipher what you are trying to do from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access `num` which is assigned in `letter_grade`. You must use the return value of the function call (ie `num, letter = letter_grade`) to read the result.

It should also be noted that `Fixnum#each` (ie `(num).each`) is not a method. `10.times { ... }` already makes a loop though, so I think this was just an oversight on your part.

See the **bolded** section for changes. I also changed your fibonacci function to calculate in linear time (instead of exponential time)

```
GradeAvg = [[59, 'F'], [69, 'D'], [79, 'C'], [89, 'B'], [100, 'A']]

def number_grade
  loop do
    print "Please insert a number between 1 and 100."
    num = gets.to_i
    break(num) if (1..100).cover?(num)
  end
end

def letter_grade
  num = number_grade
  _, letter = GradeAvg.find { |n, _| num <= n }
  [num, letter]
end

def fib (n, a = 0, b = 1)
  if n == 0 then
    a
  else
    fib n - 1, b, a + b
  end
end

10.times do
  num, letter = letter_grade
  puts letter
  puts (fib num)
end
```

Example program execution

```
# Please insert a number between 1 and 100. 95
# A
# 31940434634990099905
# Please insert a number between 1 and 100. 87
# B
# 679891637638612258
# Please insert a number between 1 and 100. 77
# C
# 5527939700884757
# Please insert a number between 1 and 100. 66
# D
# 27777890035288
# Please insert a number between 1 and 100. 55
# F
# 139583862445
# Please insert a number between 1 and 100. 10
# F
# 55
# Please insert a number between 1 and 100. ...
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
GradeAvg = [[59, 'F'], [69, 'D'], [79, 'C'], [89, 'B'], [100, 'A']]

def letter_grade
  @num = number_grade
  _, letter = GradeAvg.find { |n, _| @num <= n }
  [@num, letter]
end

def number_grade
  loop do
    puts 'Please insert a number between 1 and 100.'
    @num = gets.to_i
    break(@num) if (1..100).cover?(@num)
  end
end

def fib(n)
  return n if n < 2

  fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end

10.times { print letter_grade; puts fib(@num)}
```